# i want create constraint in django

Tags: django

I want to create a constraint of the form code = <min_weight> - <max_weight> <weight_unit>

how do i do that i just learned it

```
class Size(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
uni = [("GC", "Gram/Con"), ("KC", "Kg/Con")]
min_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
max_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
weight_uni = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=uni, default="KC")

def __str__(self):
    return self.code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `code` is 100% determined by values of other fields, there is no need to store it as separate field in db. Rather, make it a property, like this:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    uni = [("GC", "Gram/Con"), ("KC", "Kg/Con")]
    min_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    max_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    weight_uni = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=uni, default="KC")

    @property
    def code(self):
        return '%s - %s %s' % (self.min_weight, self.max_weight, self.weight_uni)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save() method and configure the following:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.code = self.min_weight - self.max_weight*self.weight_unit
        return super(Size, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That way each time a save is called(it is called when a value is changed) it will reevaluate the "code" field and update it if necessary.

Here is an example how to use constraints but I don't think that you would be able to achieve the same result:

```
    class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
            name='SimpleConstaint',
            check=(models.Q(sold_units__gte=0)&models.Q(sold_units__lte=100))
        )
    ]
```